# Estou tendo alguns problemas com GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by

Estou com dificuldade para montar um select com o `GROUP BY`. O que quero fazer é o seguinte:

Tenho três tabelas:

```
bicos                           
    idbico, idempresa, idbomba 

abastecimentos
    idabastec, idbico, idempresa, valorabastecim

bomba
    idbomba, idempresa
```

Quero trazer todos os bicos independente de terem abastecimento ou não no dia. Caso não tenha abastecimento, eu quero que o bico apareça, mas venha zerado, no meu `select` o bico só vem com abastecimento.

```
SELECT p.number
      ,h.number
      ,p.physicalnumber
      ,t.number AS tanknumber
      ,g.name AS fuelname
      ,SUM(CASE
             WHEN d.type = 6 THEN
              volume
             ELSE
              0
           END) AS testdelivery
      ,FIRST(oldvolumeetot ORDER BY completeddate) AS startvolumeetot
      ,LAST(newvolumeetot ORDER BY completeddate) AS endvolumeetot
      ,SUM(CASE
             WHEN d.type NOT IN (6) THEN
              volume
             ELSE
              0
           END) AS volume
      ,SUM(CASE
             WHEN d.type NOT IN (6) THEN
              VALUE
             ELSE
              0
           END) AS VALUE

  FROM hoses h
  JOIN pumps AS p
    ON h.stationid = p.stationid
   AND h.pumpid = p.pumpid
   AND h.number = p.number
  JOIN tanks AS t
    ON h.stationid = t.stationid
   AND h.tankid = t.tankid
  JOIN grades AS g
    ON t.stationid = g.stationid
   AND t.gradeid = g.gradeid
  LEFT JOIN deliveries AS d
    ON h.stationid = d.stationid
   AND h.hoseid = d.hoseid
   AND h.tankid = d.tankid
 WHERE h.stationid = 130
   AND completeddate >= '2018/05/17'
 GROUP BY h.stationid
         ,p.number
         ,h.number
         ,p.physicalnumber
         ,t.number
         ,g.name

 ORDER BY p.physicalnumber;
```

Comment: o select deve começar pela tabela de bicos, e depois usar left join com as outras tabelas

Comment: Já tentei, mas não adiantou.

Comment: tenta colocar os filtros do where no join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo que sua estrutura de dados seja algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_bico
(
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_empresa BIGINT,
  id_bomba BIGINT
);


CREATE TABLE tb_abastecimento
(
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_bico BIGINT,
  id_empresa BIGINT,
  valor NUMERIC(10,2),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_bico) REFERENCES tb_bico(id)
);
```

Cadastrando `Bicos`:

```
INSERT INTO tb_bico ( id ) VALUES ( 1 );
INSERT INTO tb_bico ( id ) VALUES ( 2 );
INSERT INTO tb_bico ( id ) VALUES ( 3 );
INSERT INTO tb_bico ( id ) VALUES ( 4 );
```

Cadastrando `Abastecimentos` no `Bico` com identificador `1`:

```
INSERT INTO tb_abastecimento ( id, id_bico, valor  ) VALUES ( 100, 1, 120.50 );
INSERT INTO tb_abastecimento ( id, id_bico, valor  ) VALUES ( 200, 1, 420.90 );
```

Cadastrando `Abastecimentos` no `Bico` com identificador `2`:

```
INSERT INTO tb_abastecimento ( id, id_bico, valor  ) VALUES ( 300, 2, 20.35 );
INSERT INTO tb_abastecimento ( id, id_bico, valor  ) VALUES ( 400, 2, 10.50 );
INSERT INTO tb_abastecimento ( id, id_bico, valor  ) VALUES ( 500, 2, 22.10 );
INSERT INTO tb_abastecimento ( id, id_bico, valor  ) VALUES ( 600, 2, 12.45 );
```

Repare que os `Bicos` com os identificadores `3` e `4` não possuem `Abastecimentos`.

**Solução:**

```
SELECT
  bc.id AS id_bico,
  ab.id AS id_abastecimento,
  COALESCE( ab.valor, 0.0 ) AS valor
FROM
  tb_bico AS bc
LEFT JOIN
  tb_abastecimento AS ab ON ( bc.id = ab.id_bico );
```

Saída:

```
| id_bico | id_abastecimento | valor |
|---------|------------------|-------|
|       1 |              100 | 120.5 |
|       1 |              200 | 420.9 |
|       2 |              300 | 20.35 |
|       2 |              400 |  10.5 |
|       2 |              500 |  22.1 |
|       2 |              600 | 12.45 |
|       4 |           (null) |     0 |
|       3 |           (null) |     0 |
```

Caso você queira uma consulta para retornar o *valor total* de todos os `Abastecimentos` em cada um dos `Bicos`:

```
SELECT
  bc.id AS id_bico,
  SUM( COALESCE( ab.valor, 0.0 ) ) AS valor_total
FROM
  tb_bico AS bc
LEFT JOIN
  tb_abastecimento AS ab ON ( bc.id = ab.id_bico )
GROUP BY
  bc.id;
```

Saída:

```
| id_bico | valor_total |
|---------|-------------|
|       2 |        65.4 |
|       4 |           0 |
|       1 |       541.4 |
|       3 |           0 |
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/54a328/5